# How do you use a CSS sprite sheet as a background?

Tags: html, css

I want to use part of an image (a CSS sprite sheet) as the background but I don't think there's a way to define it.

Say for example I have an `<a>` tag that is 100px wide and 30px high. I want to use an icon as the background image from a sprite sheet. Although I can position it correctly I can't 'trim' the sprite sheet to only include that icon, it continues displaying the rest of the sprite sheet because the icon is only 16x16 pixels and the `<a>` tag is much bigger.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to reserve some space for it in your sheet and make it transparent.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to create a `span` inside your `a`.

Make the `span` an `inline-block` element and then set its `width` and `height` to that of the sprite.

Another way would be to use the css `clip` property. You can find a good overview here: http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites-with-inline-images/